# SimpleXML load fails to get namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces, simplexml

When I try to get namespaces I've got a wrong result, SimpleXML extension was loaded no errors thrown.

NOTE: On the local machine, I also cannot reproduce, but in shared host it always reproducible, is there any reasons why?

Snippet:

```
<?php
$xmlString = <<<DATA
<?xml  version="1.0" ?>
<some version="2.0" xmlns:a="test0" xmlns:b="test1" xmlns:c="test2"></some>
DATA;
$xml = simplexml_load_string( $xmlString );
var_dump($xml->getDocNamespaces());
```

Result:

```
array(1) {
  [""]=>
  string(5) "test0"
}
```

Expected:
get

```
a=>test0,
b=>test1,
c=>test2
```

Is there any options or reasons why simplexml doesn't fetch that namespaces?

P.S.
I have tried to use simplexml_load_file, simplexml_import_dom(new DomDocument -> loadXML..), all of them return same result

P.S.2.

```
PHP Version 5.6.29
SimpleXML
Simplexml support   enabled
Revision    $Id: d7077fc935154236afb4fe70814ba358efdbdca4 $
Schema support  enabled
```

Comment: When I run your code I get the following:

array(3) { ["a"]=> string(5) "test0" ["b"]=> string(5) "test1" ["c"]=> string(5) "test2" }

Comment: Unable to reproduce this issue http://codepad.org/yzCD0rYO

Comment: On the local machine, I also cannot reproduce, but in shared host it always reproducible, is there any reasons why?

Comment: As I see in phpinfo  ecbiz102.inmotionhosting.com, phpinfo looks okm but anyway namespaces doesn't work

Comment: Try this http://codepad.org/8NzCnF4Z

Comment: @Bilal, actually same result. array(1) {
  [""]=>
  string(5) "test0"
}. I'm stuck

Comment: add <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133427/discussion-between---and-bilal).

Comment: We think that hosting breaks the functionality of PHP and causes issues. No more ideas to find out the reason why namespaces are not parsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: http://codepad.org/GOggdpkJ

I have added true to `getDocNamespaces(TRUE)`

```
<?php

$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<some version="2.0" xmlns:a="test0" xmlns:b="test1" xmlns:c="test2"></some>
XML;

$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$namespaces = $sxe->getDocNamespaces(TRUE);
var_dump($namespaces);

?>
```

Comment: Due to this should help I will accept the answer, but the issue still exists, and I think the only reason of hosting PHP configuration or some compiled modifications. Locally everything works fine. So for the moment we can use XMLReader or parse without namespaces. Thanks for the help.